# I'm not understanding how I can convert MVC table building to use AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I'm working on getting a better understanding on how to use AJAX to populate a table in an MVC View. I've got a table being built in my View and now I want to convert it over to using AJAX.

I've watched some videos and looked over some examples but everyone of them just takes some simple values and adds them to an existing table. That's all good if there is no real logic to look when creating each row but what do you do when you need logic?

Example, here is an example of my MVC View. I loop through my List and conditionally look at each record item to determine if I display some buttons or not.

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.listExceptions)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.InsertDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")</td>
        <td>@item.CommentText</td>
        <td>
            @if (item.Status.ToUpper() != "A" && item.Status.ToUpper() != "D" && Model.isAdmin == true)
            {
                <a href="@Url.Action("ExceptionApproveDeny", "Exception", new { rid=item.RID, arg="A", shift=item.ShiftDate })" 
                   onclick="return confirm('APPROVE this exception?')" 
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                    <span class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Approve
                </a>

                <a href="@Url.Action("ExceptionApproveDeny", "Exception", new { rid=item.RID, arg="D", shift=item.ShiftDate })" 
                   onclick="return confirm('DENY this exception?')" 
                   class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                    <span class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></span> Deny
                </a>
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

However, all of the examples I've found working with AJAX they manually create a a table row and just append it to the end of the table. This is the code from one of the examples I looked at.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
    //Call EmpDetails jsonResult Method  
    $.getJSON("Home/EmpDetails",  
    function (json) {  
    var tr;  
    //Append each row to html table  
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {  
            tr = $('<tr/>');  
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Id + "</td>");  
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Name + "</td>");  
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].City + "</td>");  
            tr.append("<td>" + json[i].Address + "</td>");  
            $('table').append(tr);  
        }  
    });
```

How can I run conditional code like I did in my View but using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. One way is to add a new property to the view model or data structure you are returning from the action EmpDetails to include the url. You can use Url.Action helper inside your controller code to generate the url and send it.

```
public class ItemVm
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public string Address{ set;get;}
  public string ApprovalUrl { set;get;}
}
```

and in the controller action, you set the ApprovalUrl property. In the below example i am hard coding it for the first item. But you can conditionally do it with the same checks you have in question.

```
public ActionResult EmpDetails()
{
  var list = new List<ItemVm>();

  list.Add(new ItemVm { Id=1, Name="John", 
              ApprovalUrl=Url.Action("ExceptionApproveDeny",new { rid=1,arg="A"}) });

  list.Add(new ItemVm { Id=1, Name="Scott" });
  return Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now in the ajax call, you check the `ApprovalUrl` exist for each item you are iterating in the loop and use it.

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("EmpDetails")",function(json) {
        var tr;
        $.each(json,function(i, item) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + item.Name + "</td>");
                if (item.ApprovalUrl) {
                    tr.append("<td> <a href='" + item.ApprovalUrl + "'>Approve</a></td>");
                } else {
                    tr.append("<td></td>");
                }
                $('#yourTableId').append(tr);
        });
});
```

Another option is to return the HTML markup for the entier table.So instead of returning the JSON data, you return a partial view result inside which you can have the same code you shared in the question.

```
public ActionResult EmpDetails()
{
   var items = new List<ItemVm>();
   // to do :load items
   return PartialView(items);
}
```

The view of this action method can have the same code you have in your question in terms of conditionally rendering the links.

```
@model List<ItemVm>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name</td>            
            <!-- add code for other td here-->
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

and now all you have to do is update the table element markup in current DOM

```
$.get("@Url.Action("EmpDetails")",function(result) {
    $('#yourTableId').html(result);
});
```

I prefer the second approach as it is less prone to errors and the same partial view can be reused

If you use something like angular/react or view, all you do is set the underlying data source array to the new json data and that library/framework will update the ui for you from the template you defined.

**Never trust data coming from client**. **Always validate things in server**. So i suggest you to update the `ExceptionApproveDeny` action method to do the necessary checks before doing any data updates.

Comment: Very cool! I like the looks of the second approach. I haven't seen that before and I'm surprised this type of example isn't posted in an article or video somewhere. I'm going to see if I can get it implemented in my scenario and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code for your Jquery use.
Its simple and I have not created complicated using partial view and other stuffs.

you can be able to use the same conditions which you are using in view but you have to add "" manually using HTML append.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/EmpDetails',
    type: 'Get',
    success: function(data){
            // Here you need to make one more call to get whether user is 
            // Admin or not.
            // for that you can make callback function here.
            GetIfUserIsAdmin(function(isAdmin){
            // here you can use $.each loop and based on condition which you  
            // are adding in your view you can put same condition and append 
            // HTML
            // If you are using angular you have to just create a template  
            //  and pass the value and based on your template angular will          
            // generate desired HTML based on your conditions which you give 
            // while building your template.
         })  
    },
    error: function(){
        app.log("Device control failed");
    },
});

function GetIfUserIsAdmin(callback){
    // Here you need to make a ajax call which will provide you IsUser is       
    // Admin or not and call the callback function with that flag
    // information from the success event of your ajax function.
    $.ajax({
    url: '/home/IsAdmin',
    type: 'Get',
    success: function(isUserAdmin){ // you can pass only true or false here
                    if(data != '' && data != undefined && data != null){
          callback(isUserAdmin);
          }
          else{
          console.log('Check is User is admin function in you code.')
          }

    },
    error: function(){
        app.log("Device control failed");
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look this over some and see if it will work in my scenario.